# bridging iphone to a wifi AP that's connected by ethernet to a computer that's on a another wifi network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

I've got a Fuji Instax SP-1 printer thing, that's used by connecting to a WiFi network it sets up when you want to print to it. I also have an iMac, which is connected via Ethernet to a Time Machine, which is running in bridged mode connected to my apartment building's internet connection, and to which my iPhone connects to via Wifi.

I'd like to bridge these networks via the iMac, if it's possible - the goal is for the phone, on the Time Machine's wifi, to see the printer, on the Wifi network the printer runs, and which the iMac is connected to. (so the real goal is, I can print from my phone without mucking around with the wifi settings).

The phone and iMac can already ping each other, and the Instax's IP is well known, so 'all' I need to do is make it that when my iPhone tries to reach 192.168.0.251, my iMac forwards that to the 192.168.0.251 that it knows about (and then that replies go the other way). The phone, imac, and time machine are all on a 172.16.64.0/18 network, and the imac to printer wifi network is a 192.168.0.0/16 network.

Is this possible, and how? I suspect that the time machine sitting between my iPhone and my iMac might be a blocker - i do have a raspberry pi 3 sitting around which I believe I could use as an AP instead, if that'd help.

Comment: Do you really need full bridging (as in, one subnet)? Your 3rd paragraph sounds very much like you only want IP reachability (routing), not bridging.

Comment: could very well be using the wrong terminology - would be completely happy if my phone, on one wifi network, can reach the printer, at a known ip address, on another wifi network (with a couple of ethernet connected devices in the middle).

Answer (score 0):

I wound up doing this with a raspberry PI as a wifi router and some NAT-ing/proxying  - iptables NAT my phone's connection to the rasbpi to the iMac over ethernet, connect iMac's wifi to printer, and tcp proxy on iMac to printer. Probably could've NATed from iMac to printer as well, but got bored of messing with pf, and it turns out I only needed tcp packets on port 8080 forwarded anyway.

So if anyone needs a horribly impractical way of setting up their home network such that you can print to an instax without changing wifi networks, that's how you do it.